# Share files over Internet (SMB? VPN?)

Tags: vpn, smb, drobo

I manage backups for my parents and I in two separate locations. Parents have a Drobo5N. I want to be able to access the files on that easily and visually so that I can backup their files at my location as well. The built-in DroboAccess is very clunky and every change/download involves clicking a million times. Moving files within their server in particular involves 5 menus.

1. Is there a way to see the drive, much as if I had "mapped" the drive if I was on the local network?
2. Which protocol would you use? e.g. SMB? VPN?
3. How would you set this up on a Verizon FiOS Actiontec router?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello Ted, welcome to Superuser. You might want to check out https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask - we don't have a lot of detail to go on.  Include what research you've done, what have you already tried, what file share protocols does Drobo5n support?  We're not experts on specific hardware, so you may have to do some of your own research  I think what you're asking to do is possible but it might not be as simple as just setting up a mapped drive and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be similar questions out there that just refers to different hardware.  That said here's a generic approach that I would use:

Drobo5n looks like a fairly standard NAS (Network Attached Storage) system and most types I've worked with support FTP.  A quick google tells me that their system support NFS and FTP.  You will probably need to do something along these lines:

- Enable NFS / FTP or set it up as per manufacturer instructions
- On the router connected to the device, create a port forwarding rule for the NAS.
- If the router has it's own firewall, it might need the port / ip allowing through it.
- Test the FTP / NFS connection on your PC on a program of your choice.  FTP can be set up natively in Windows File Explorer.

If you get stuck I'd recommend you visit the manufacturers websites and read their guides on their products.  All the best :)